# Changes in compression rate

Tags: compression, rar

Every month I usually compress all my database dumps into a rar file.

I was very happy with the compression rate, as each compressed file was usually about 30MB, with a compression rate of 99%.

Since a few weeks ago, without having touched anything (neither in the compressor parameters nor in the dump system), the compression rate has dropped to 70% and now the compressed file occupies about 1.50GB.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: you may try with xz if it gets better ratio imho

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening due to the database containing less compressible stuff.

Generally the level of compression depends on the context. Pure text (e.g. a natural language) compresses really well, while already compressed formats such as JPEG or PNG doesn't compress at all.

You should look into what content you have in your database, and how the various content types are affected.